# AD, SSRS, and Parameter dropdowns

Tags: reporting-services, active-directory

We have 46 buildings in our company and we want to write reports that allow all buildings to see their data.  We have 46 AD groups we've created for another application.  What I'd like to do is to populate a dropdown parameter full of the building names, but only show them based on your access in AD.

example: 
Administrator1 has access to Building1.  He is in group1.
Administrator1 has access to Building2.  He is in group2.
Regional1 has access to buildings 1-5.  She is in group1, group2, group3, group4, and group5
Exec1 has access to all buildings.  She is in all groups.

Exec1 would see all buildings, Admins only their buildings and Regional the group of buildings.  Can I populate a parameter dropdown with only the values these people have based on a lookup when they hit the report?

Answer (score 1):

I've used a couple of methods to solve similar problems:
First create an internal parameter for the report which will contain the user's id. "=User!UserID"
Next you need to get the permissions joined in. This is easiest if you have the user to group/permission mapping somewhere in SQL. Then this is just a SQL join.

Otherwise, you can set up a Active Directory "Linked Server" which can query AD for group members. This can take some patience and troubleshooting time. Once set up, you can join to the membership of each group.

If I were building what you describe, I would code an AD to SQL data export to run at regular intervals (a .NET .exe), keeping a SQL table up to date with permissions. This would be easier to set up and more robust than the SQL-> AD Linked Server.

I can find references for the linked server approach if that would be helpful...

Comment: hmm, so you create a linked server, hit it periodically filling up a table with the results, and query the join of that and a permissions table based on what?  (sorry, hit return too quickly)  How do I determine who they are?  We've done it in dotnetnuke by getting their rolegroups.  I just don't know how to grab the info when they come to the page.

Comment: Depends on how sensitive to performance you are, and with 46 groups, I'm not sure how I'd structure the query, but I've actively queried the linked server in my SP by group name on-demand to generate the report. Keeps the results real-time for security changes, but slows things down a bit.  Use the results of this query to populate your parameter available choices.

Comment: There's an article at [http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1657] that shows how to import AD users and groups into SQL, I've used this to do the same thing (mapping in reports)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the `memberOf` attribute in AD and loop on the result with a mathching regular expression, I think that you can build your combo.